# Can We use some pictures for our school project

Tags: discussion, legal

This is cleveland middle school. We are doing a project which needs a picture of a prosthetic arm. Could we possibly use your site's picture for our project.we will cite your name in the credit.

Comment: Uhhh... we have one of those? I think maybe you're talking about a different site.

Comment: Do you mean the "angel" image? That was created by Stack Overflow designer [Jin](http://meta.stackexchange.com/users/147574/jin). All of the artwork on this site, belongs to this site, so it conforms to the cc by-sa 3.0 (attribution required) licence as pointed out by [Ixrec](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/8149/21267)

Comment: Something smells fishy here, but I don't know what it is.

Comment: **My previous comment was incorrect, the correct answer is *[no](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9167/21267)***

Answer (score 4):

Quoth the footer of the site:

> user contributions licensed under [cc by-sa 3.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) with [attribution required](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/)

So yes, assuming you're talking about a post someone put in one of our questions or answers (and they had the right to put it there in the first place), then it's totally okay for you to use it elsewhere, as long as you give proper attribution. Those two links should provide more than enough detail on what that means.

Comment: Assuming the user had the license to use the image in the first place. Otherwise finding the original creator may need to be done to cite it properly.

Comment: I think this seems incorrect, since the site's logos and design are Trademarks and Copyrights since they are not content contributed by users. See [my answer](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9167/21267) for clarification.

Answer (score 4):

I think what you're looking for is the ability to use some of the site's designs and pictures for your school project.

If this is correct; [then you are ***not*** allowed to use them](http://stackexchange.com/legal/trademark-guidance). Unless you ask them specifically first and they tell you it's ok.

However, [I Am Not A Lawyer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IANAL).

**Trademark and Copyright**
You see, the site's logo(s), name and design(s) are a [Trademark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trademark) of **[StackOverflow inc](http://stackexchange.com/about)**; which means that if you use it in a way which is identifiable, then people will think that you are owned/endorsed *by* StackOverflow.

As per their legal info:

> ### Trademark and Copyright
>
> The logos associated with Stack Exchange Inc. and any Stack Exchange site are a trademark. The purpose of trademark law is to prevent consumers from being misled as to the origin of the product. So if you were making a product, and you used a Stack Exchange name or logo in your product (or in its advertising) in such a way that would mislead someone into thinking that your product was owned by, operated by, endorsed by, or in any way part of Stack Exchange Inc., you would be violating the trademark and this would not be legal.
> Our logo images and site names are copyrighted. Any content on the Stack Exchange Network **not contributed by users** is copyrighted. Copyright is different than trademark. Ordinarily you couldn't copy it. But if you were writing a news story or blog post about a Stack Exchange site, reproducing the logo image would almost certainly be considered "fair use" and allowed under trademark law because you were not using it "in trade".
>
> ...
>
> *The Stack Exchange name and logos are trademarks of Stack Exchange Inc. The names and logos for sites and products operating on the Stack Exchange network are also trademarks of Stack Exchange Inc.*

**Fair Use**
Since you claim that you are a school, if you were to be using or referencing any of these Trademarked or Copyright materials, then your use may fall under the ["Fair Use"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fair_use) policy. However, even if you are a school, if your usage promotes your school in any way enabling you to make money, then most likely it will not.

When I did "Intellectual Property Law" as part of my university studies, generally the "rule of thumb" was that if you're going to be making money from someone else's work in any way, then it is not allowed, however, this was in Australia and again, IANAL.

**Best to ask**
If you would like to use anything from this site (which is not deemed content contributed by *users* of the site), then you should consider contacting the StackOverlow team and ask them for permission.

You may find that the StackOverflow staff can sometimes be very giving and lenient and might go "yeah sure go for it, no problem".

Use the [contact form](https://meta.stackexchange.com/contact) which can be found at the bottom of every page.

Comment: I would add to this, though, that there are usually exceptions to copyright use when it comes to educational purposes.

Comment: @CreationEdge Yes, that falls under the ["fair use"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fair_use) rules as mentioned.